# Why use V43 over vii°6?

Tags: voice-leading

It seems that there is a leap of a 4th when moving from I6 to V43. wouldnt a descending bassline with ^2 having a vii°6 be smoother in connecting I6 with I53? Or perhaps there is another good reason to use V43?
[image]

Comment: How do you avoid having a leap with vii°6?

Comment: key signature..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you propose `I6 viio6 I` you gloss over the main issue to consider: which tones get doubled in triads in *four* part harmony.

The reason for the leap in the example is because the *tonic* is doubled. If you double the fifth of `I6` then the leap is avoided...

[image]

If you did it with three parts, keeping the main bass and soprano, I think the basic voice leading for all step-wise motion would be...

[image]

...where FA would resolve to MI and SOL is omitted from the final `I` chord.

Finally, if you want `I6 viio6 I` in three parts, *complete* triads, while maintaining tendency tone movements, you cannot avoid a leap. So, I think the thing to do is put the leap in the inner voice so the outer voices are in smooth steps, like this...

[image]

Now, back to the question:

> Why use V43 over vii°6?

I think it really is just the same as any other harmony choice. Melodic considerations, wanting to ensure or avoid certain melodic intervals. Harmonic considerations, wanting the "fuller" sound of a seventh chord, the particular resonance of a fourth, the lighter sound of triadic `viio6`, etc.

Perhaps the point to make is "smooth" voice leading may be defined as *step-wise* voice movement, but that doesn't necessarily mean the *only* good voice leading is smooth, step-wise motion.

Answer (score 2):

Using V4/3 instead of vii°6 allows the tenor to keep the B like it's a pedal tone. It's also possible that the composer just plain likes the sound of V4/3 better than vii°6 there.

Switching to vii°6 does let you use E-F♯ (presumably)-G♯ (presumably) in the alto and B-A-B in the tenor, though...

Comment: ok but doesnt the fact that you have to leap a 4th to make the progression mean it is not as good as using a vii°6?

Comment: @armani - If the composer just plain likes the sound of V4/3 better than vii°6 there, I'd think that the chord progression being "not as good" voice leading-wise would have been no obstacle, and the composer would make V4/3 work no matter what.

Comment: @armani how do you voice the chords?  The tenor has to have ^5 ^4 ^3; ^5 ^4 ^5 frustrates the expected downward resolution of ^4 to ^3. 
What then does the alto do?  It can't be ^1 ^2 ^3 because that doubles the third in the last chord.  Stepwise motion ^1 ^2 ^1 or ^1 ^7 ^1 yields parallel octaves with bass or soprano.  With a four voice texture you're going to have a leap of some sort with vii°6, too.

Comment: Phoog see this example https://ibb.co/swLCK0z 2nd bar 2nd chord

Comment: @armani - Note that the example you have uses ^1 ^2 ^3 in the soprano, which dodges all the parallel octave problems phoog mentions while letting an inner voice still use ^5 ^4 ^3. Looks like that soprano in your OP is screwing things up even further than we initially thought.

Comment: Ok but even with ^1^2^3 in the soprano, there will still be a 4th leap in the progression I63 V43 I right? By using vii6 you avoid that.

Comment: @armani - Actually, ^1 ^2 ^3 cannot support V4/3 to harmonize ^2 at all unless you use 5 or more voices, since you need a ^2 in the bass and the soprano and ^5, ^7, and ^4 elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The rule that  in a 6th chord (1st inversion) the root tone has to be doubled has no statistical fundament. If we double here the 3rd (G#) the progression has no leap at all.

Comment: It is not statistical but I do kind of dislike the doubled 3rd... it overtakes the sound of the root of the chord IMO. And perhaps why many use the 3rd as a last resort when doubling

Comment: I've posted here else where an statistical research by Diether De la Motte of the doubled chord tones in the music of Bach, Handel and Haydn.